# Which inheritance type should I use for multiple user levels in Doctrine

Tags: php, oop, doctrine-orm

I am new to OOP and I am confused how should I proceed. My main requirement is that I want to have base user class:

```
User
id
username
email
password
salt
.....

Student
name
gender
school
address

Teacher
name
study
salary
```

I am confused if I should use single table inheritance or class table inheritance. Because all students or teacher are going to log into system so I wanted to keep that data common

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Student and Teacher are both Users, so Student extends from User, and so does Teacher.

Checking whether inheritance is legit, can be done by saying 'is a' between the 2 objects.

"Student is a Teacher" -> false

"Student is a User" -> true

Answer (score 0):

Since `Student` and `Teacher` have extra and different fields, you should go with Class Table Inheritance. Single Table Inheritance will force you to have a lot of rows with several `NULL` values, which is a bad idea from the DB design standpoint.

BTW, since you have the `name` field in both child classes, you could move it up the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you these books. They make this topic really clear.

- PHP Design Patterns
- Clean Code (Robert C. Martin)

They help you to understand, how to build clean and maintainable software with clear relations between objects. Must-read for all OOP-Users, I think!